# Why do I need to specify a Namespace manager for Xpath querys

Tags: c#, xml

When querying an XmlDocument I need to pass a namespace manager over with each call. Annoying really but it's just something we live with. The really annoying bit is creating the namespace manager in the first place.

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsMan = new XmlNamespaceManager(invoiceTextReader.NameTable);
nsMan.AddNamespace("", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2");
nsMan.AddNamespace("pb", "urn:pierbridge:names:specification:pbl:schema:xsd:tpn-1");
...
```

To create it I need to not only seed the instance with the nametable but then specify every single namespace manually. This seems so silly to me. What's the point in passing the name table if I have to go and add them all manually. And what's the point of passing the name table if I then need to pass the namespace manager back for each and every query. Why can't it just build the namespace manager from what's contained in the document right off the bat. Seems like an awful lot of faffing just to run a query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NamespaceManager must be passed in if your XPaths have namespace prefixes. Below is list of cases when you don't need namespace manager:

- if all your nodes are in default (empty) namespace you can just use `/a/b/c` as XPath
- if you prefer to manually specify namespace/name pairs for each node like `*[namespace-uri()='urn:oasis:names' & name()='node1']`.
- if you can use parent/child, position and siblings only in XPath

You pass NameTable to allow faster string comparison - same strings are actually the same object if document and namespace manager share the same NameTable. You don't actually have to pass the same NameTable.

You must specify only those prefixes that are used in your XPath. It is often much less than all namespaces in the document. The mapping can't be automatically computed from the XML since prefix to namespace mapping is arbitrary.

This is an example of XML where all prefixes are the same, but map to different namespace each time to show actual need for custom mapping of prefixes in the XPath:

```
<a:a xmlns='a:my1'>
 <a:a xmlns='a:my2' />
 <a:a xmlns='a:my3' />
</a>
```

Comment: Oh I see, didn't know you could redefine a namespace within a document. I would still think it's possible to automatically figure out the namespaces based on the position in the document but that would be dramatically more complicated to do. Regardless thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/e5t11tzt%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) states:

> Qualifying element and attribute names with a namespace prefix limits the nodes returned by an XPath query to only those nodes that belong to a specific namespace.
>
> For example if the prefix books maps to the namespace http://www.contoso.com/books, then the following XPath query /books:books/books:book selects only those book elements in the namespace http://www.contoso.com/books.

Furthermore:

> XPath treats the empty prefix as the null namespace. In other words, only prefixes mapped to namespaces can be used in XPath queries. This means that if you want to query against a namespace in an XML document, even if it is the default namespace, you need to define a prefix for it.

So that should answer your question.

Comment: That doesn't answer his question. That's the reason why you need to specify the namespaces. He asks, why XmlDocument can't populate the XmlNamespaceManager automatically from the provided XML file.

Comment: Thankyou for the response but as already kindly pointed out I'm not asking why namespaces exist. I'm wondering why the namespace manager needs to be hard coded in such a laborious way and then passed with every single call.

Comment: What would be the point of having the XmlDocument populating the XmlNamespaceManager? To construct an Xpath expression you would  have to query the namespace manager for the prefixes used for the particular namespaces, and then assemble a suitable query. That's more work than constructing the manager directly. Besides, the question really is an answer, especially the second sentence  in the second quoted paragraph.